# Pylzma decompression slow down

Tags: python, 7zip, lzma

I am using https://github.com/fancycode/pylzma 's py7zlib.py to decompress a big file with ultra high compression rate.

for example, a 7z file contains 450K small files

At first, it decommpress well.

And then it starts to slow down the decompression speed to zero...

```
500 of 449981   0% |                                | ETA:  0:13:09 569.14  B/s


12500 of 449981   2% |                              | ETA:  9:54:04  12.27  B/s
```

Is any optimization or parameter for increasing the speed?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [available docs](https://github.com/fancycode/pylzma/blob/master/doc/USAGE.md), nothing seems suitable. The only one: **multithreading** is on by default.

Also is sounds kind of weird that there would be a parameter `let do stuff faster`.

Comment: maybe just use more memory or lower the compression rate? I dont know~ I was shocked by this slowest speed.....

Comment: @jackypan1989 definitely if you will use lower compression, the speed would be faster.